# WPF Screen padding and margin issue with scaling 150

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, uwp

I am creating a wpf application which have webview.
I have used the dynamic binding to set width and height to webview.
Here the issue is for all resolution webview is showing properly at any scaling factor except 150% .
Screen is starting with gap starting from top . I have checked no where I have used any margin or padding still only for 150% scaling I am able to see the gap.

I tried to fetch the margin programmatically but I can see no margin and padding

Attaching the screenshots

Screen top at 100% and 125 % with any resolution :
[image: 100% / 125 %]

Screen top at 150 %

[image: the black screen is the gap , screen start should show white portion]

Comment: <StackPanel  Name="stackPanel" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <WebView x:Name="webView1" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=stackPanel}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight,ElementName=stackPanel}" Source="http://www.contoso.com"/>
    </StackPanel>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is working for 100% and not for 150% then I think you are using the wrong dimension for your application.
Make sure your minHeight is correct , for main windows and for webview page.

I am sure for 100% the height is 1080 , but for 150% height will be near about 720
Make sure min height is set below 720

Comment: In Main page I am using MinHeight="860" and for webpage I am using  d:DesignHeight="350" . Which one should I change ?

Comment: That's the issue , so whenever you are using 150% height is 720 but due to min height it will take the height of 860 . reduce the min height value in main windows . no need to change any value to webview page

Comment: I am facing same issue but above solution not worked. The Webview2 in WPF VSTO app do not displayed at proper place.